# Database login failed localDB in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: c#

So I am using localDB in my .net core web 2.0. My connection string is like this

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=ShoppingWebsiteMVC;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
}
```

It works fine on my machine but when I send the project to another machine and try to run it there locally it says

> Database login failed

Is there a way to solve this? Like giving permissions to everyone or create a user for that?

Comment: is LocalDB installed on the machine? Does it have an instance name "mssqllocaldb" ? Use the command line and do `sqllocaldb i`